# Is there a way to download the iOS 13 public beta IPSW?

Tags: ios, itunes, ipsw

I'm looking for the public beta IPSW (specifically, the iOS 13 public beta 4), so I can update my iPhone via my Mac, instead of over the air.

https://ipsw.me does not seem to have them, and Apple Developer Portal only shows me the Xcode beta as an available download.

How can I download the software bundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to download the IPSW files for public betas of iOS/iPadOS 13. You can, however, download the IPSW of the developer betas.

To do so, you should be a registered member of the Apple Developer program enrolled into a paid membership. Once you have the paid membership, visit the Apple Developer Download page(s) below to access and download the respective IPSWs:

- https://developer.apple.com/download/#ios-restore-images-iphone-new
- https://developer.apple.com/download/#ios-restore-images-ipad-new

Comment: I must admit, it is not the reply I was hoping for... Is there a statement as to why this is the case, because on the website, it appears as if you should be able to download the public beta IPSW

Comment: Sorry but asking *WHY* Apple does anything is officially off-topic here. Because Apple tells no one who doesn't work at Apple why they do anything, so discussing it is fruitless and left as an exercise in income enhancement for Mac columnists.